# Wokflow manager 1.0 refresh upgrades

Tags: 2013, workflow, workflow-manager, service-bus

While upgrading workflow manager 1.0 to Workflow Manager 1.0 refresh, do we need to run workflow manager config wizard after done installing workflow manager 1.0 refresh from web platform installer?

What about the pre-requisite service bus 1.0 CU 1, do we need to run config wizard?

As far as I know, I will do the following to upgrade workflow manager from 1.0 to 1.0 refresh.

1. install Service Bus 1.0 CU 1 on all workflow servers using web platform installer.
    Reboot
2. install Workflow Manager 1.0 Refresh on all workflow servers using web platform installer
   Reboot
3. install Workflow Manager Client 1.0 Refresh on all workflow servers using web platform installer (Do we need to install this tool in SharePoint Servers too)
4. Run (Register-SPWorkflowService) on SharePoint Servers.

Answer (score 1):

I am positive you dont need to run the config wizard after WF manager updates.

Software requirements:

- PowerShell 3.0 must be installed on the computer to be updated.
  PowerShell 3.0 is included in the Windows Management Framework 3.0
  installation. Go to Windows Management Framework 3.0 to install this
  update
- Workflow Manager Client 1.0 must be installed on the computer.
- For computers that have Workflow Manager 1.0 installed, the following
  additional requirements apply:

### The Service Bus for Windows Server cumulative update must be installed on the whole computer farm before you install the cumulative update for Workflow Manager 1.0 2799752 Description of the Service Bus for Windows Server Cumulative Update: February 22, 2013

### Service Bus for Windows Server must be installed on the computer.

- Supported operating systems: Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows
  Server 2012 and Windows Server 2012 R2

### Workflow Manager Client 1.0 can also be independently installed on the x86 and x64 versions of Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows Server 2008.

- Credential requirements: Before you run the executable, you must have
  administrative credentials on the computer where you are installing
  the software. See the Workflow Manager documentation for more
  information.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2902007

Helpful link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/biztalknotes/archive/2014/11/20/workflow-manager-backend-service-failure-after-upgrade-to-1-0-refresh.aspx

Comment: by "whole computer farm" do they mean workflow farm? also installing new version of workflow manager and service bus from web platform installer will suffice this upgrade.

Comment: Also can you please provide the build number of workflow manager refresh and service bus CU1

Comment: Also what is difference between (Workflow Manager CU2 to get to 1.0 refresh) and (Workflow Manager 1.0 refresh) since they were released on same date. We have (workflow manager 1.0) the first release, can we upgrade to 1.0 refresh?